# vs 2019 community and angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio

So Installed the latest  and greatest visual studio community, latest and greatest Angular package,
include the angular project: Add - New Poject - " ASP.NET Core Web Application "

===== startup.cs

```
{
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{


// To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
// see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
     **spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")**
     });
};
}
```

======
That fails on the  spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")

I do not know where "ClientApp" comes from.
So I assume the Angular CLIent Server is not working. Please advise.
When I select Debug - Start Debugging,
Edge - new tab - https://localhost:44344/  fires up.

## After about a minute the edge tab shows:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests
within the timeout    period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.
WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
```

=====

where do I look?

Everything compiles and executes but the javascript half does not start up.  Where do I look?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try opening a command prompt at the ClientApp level and entering "ng serve"?